# Convert arguments of a bash script to a JSON array for a web service

Tags: json, web-services, bash, arguments

I have a web service that requires a list of arguments in a JSON format. For instance, the JSON it could handle is like this:

```
{
  "args": ["basharg1", "bash arg 2 with spaces", "lastargs"]
}
```

How can I easily transform the arguments to a bash script to build a string that holds this kind of JSON? That string would then be used by `curl` to pas it to the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it. Feel free to suggest improvements.

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS="\"$1\""
shift

while (( "$#" )); do
    ARGS="$ARGS, \"$1\""
    shift
done

ARGUMENTS_JSON="{ \"args\": [$ARGS] }"

echo "$ARGUMENTS_JSON"
```

Comment: You could also write: `ARGS=""; for arg; do printf -v ARGS '%s,"%s"' "$ARGS", "$arg"; done; ARGS=${ARGS#,}`

Comment: how does this work? I want to put all the arguments to the script $1, $2, $3, etc, into a JSON array.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac, a shorter version that uses glenn_jackman's approach is:

```
ARGS=""; for arg; do ARGS=$(printf '%s"%s"' "$ARGS", "$arg"); done;
ARGS=${ARGS#,}
JSON="{ \"args\": [$ARGS] }"
echo "$JSON"
```

Comment: I think you can probably use single quotes around the JSON string, and then you won't have to escape the double quotes; have not confirmed that though.

Comment: @AlexanderMills JSON strings are delimited by double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the single quote thing and it didn't work, so now we know :)

Comment: I am going to try this though '"{"foo":"bar"}"' (single quotes around double quotes)